# Voltage source Is shorted

Tags: power, short-circuit

I did a circuit to test it using the application everycircuit (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.everycircuit.free). But when I did the following circuit I've got the following error message: Voltage source Is shorted[image]

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: the red dots might signify the wire is running *behind* the source. Did you perhaps forget to cut up the vertical line before adding the voltage source?

Comment: It's probably complaining about the fact that a capacitor with no series resistance is a short-circuit to high frequency AC signals. And at turn-on, there's a broad spectrum of high-frequency components due to the step function.

Comment: @Felthry At 50 Hz a 10uF capacitor has an impedance of 318 ohms.

Comment: What do you mean with your question? I cut the wire up the voltage source and it works. But when I connect it on that way it doesn't work. And I have changed the components with a resistance, for example, and it still not working

Comment: @Felthry No to AC, but to freq.-> infinite

Comment: @DerStrom8 At turn-on, the capacitor sees a broad spectrum of high-frequency signals, though. This is probably not doing steady-state analysis.

Comment: The only thing that I can chance from the capacitor Is its capacitance

Comment: @F.Riggio I asked because the big junction dots only appear in three-way crossings of wires, and the source is *visibly* not connected to two wires where there are the red junction dots, so I was assuming that you simply had more wires, just hidden.

Comment: @PDuarte, I have chanced the impedancy to 100mH and capacitance to 120 microF and it happends nothing

Comment: @F.Riggio it won’t work until you don’t put a resistor between your source and the capacitor, that’s because the transition OFF-> ON of your source could produce an infinite frequency which leads to infinite current, and the software can’t handle it

Answer (score 1):

You have an inductor in parallel with the source, which, in DC, is represented as a short. Combined with a voltage source, whose internal resistance is also zero, results in an infinite current. Unless you provide some resistance between them , it will complain. The capacitor has nothing to do with it, you can see this by adding the series resistance after the capacitor.

Comment: But the voltage source depicted is clearly an AC source.

Comment: The inductor doesn't immediately reach infinite current, though. Current through an inductor can't change instantaneously.

Comment: @Felthry, what analysis were you trying to do? DC, AC, or transient?

Comment: @ThePhoton Whatever this program does, which I believe is transient from what I've seen of it elsewhere.

Comment: Try removing the capacitor and leave only the inductor, see if it works. Then the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

This same problem with calculating the initial operating point can be demonstrated with more professional simulation packages such as LTspice, however it generally doesn't arise because the inductor model defaults to a series resistance of 1m\$\Omega\$, which is reasonable enough in most cases.

[image]

If you take a simple AC source and parallel it with a perfect inductor (as I did above by explicitly setting the resistance to 0 instead of leaving it blank) it will choke as follows:

[image]

**So add 1m\$\Omega\$** (or whatever seems reasonable) in series with your inductor and it will simulate just fine. Since this program is aimed at beginners it's a shame they didn't do that as a default.

[image]

I have run into this when simulating circuits involving superconducting inductors where the resistance actually is zero, not a situation that most EEs encounter.